# Update age column in database automatically using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to update the age column day to day automatically in codeigniter. I try the following method, but it's updated correctly.
In controller

```
 $member_id = $this->cron->get_member_id();
      if(!empty($member_id))
      {
          foreach($member_id as $id)
          {
              $dob = $id['DOB'];
              $today = date("Y-m-d");
              $diff = date_diff(date_create($dob), date_create($today));
              $age = $diff->format('%y');
              $this->cron->change_age($id['Memberid'],$age);
          }

       }
```

Models

```
public function get_member_id()
 {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('registration');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
 }
 public function change_age($id,$age)
 {
    $data = array(
      'Age' => $age
    );
   $this->db->where('Memberid',$id);
   $this->db->update('registration',$data);
 }
```

Please help to resolve.

Comment: pls clear this `only half of the data only`

Comment: It's often a bad idea to store something you can easily compute. Maybe you don't need this.